# Modifying navigation menu classes with a Walker

Tags: navigation, walker

I did a class that extends Walker_Nav_Menu to modify the default classes of my < li >s but also to modify the default classes of my < ul >s. It seems that only the sub-menus are affected by the Walker. I would like to remove the classes and id of the first < ul > (the menu itself), but the walker won't let me do that.

There are some arguments in "wp_nav_menu( array $args )" that will let me change the < ul >'s class and id, but nothing to remove them. I don't want to do:

```
'menu_class' => '',
'menu_id' => '',
```

and i'm guessing there is a solution to completely remove the class and id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `items_wrap` argument ([see codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)).

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
    )
)
```

Comment: AHHHH! Perfect!